# Angular 4 materialmd- table variable column width

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a simple table example from [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) site. Is there any way how to make it's colums width based on longest cell's content? Something like [same size items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503227/how-to-make-flexbox-items-the-same-size) but applied on table columns.

Comment: What have you tried? Insert your code.

Comment: I olny tried table example from angular material siete, and setting class to ng-container ... but I found out that ng-container will not be rendered so error occurred .

Comment: You can check ngx-datatable (https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) project. It is very similar and probably it will easy to migrate to material when it provides more features for data table.