# How can I make wrapped list columns all the same width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When the list items reach to the bottom of container next items show in the next column. In this case container width divide between 3 columns. How can I change column width?
i want change column width manually
not like the result (automatic divide container width between column)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is a longer row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
</ul>
```

and result:

[image]

Comment: So what is the desired result?

Comment: no, i want change column width

Comment: I revised your post title into a specific question. Please revise further if it's not accurate, but your question wasn't initially clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make flexbox items the same size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503227/how-to-make-flexbox-items-the-same-size)

Comment: i want change column width manually not like the result (automatic divide container width between column)

Answer (score 0):

The column `width` is being reflected from the width of your `li`s. With that being said, you can change the column width by changing the width on `li`.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  border: solid 1px orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
  <li><a href="">this is row</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I recommend solutions based on flexbox rather than width calculation. This is more flexible where column count changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide like this - 100/12. If you `divide 100 by 12` we get 8.333333333333333. Now you can just `multiply` into 4 then you will get the value for `3 equal columns`.

For example: 8.333333333333333 * 4 = 33.33333333333333.

Finally just add `percentage` like this - 33.33%

In your case your `CSS` should look like this:

```
    * {
        /*to adjust paddings on columns. you can learn more about box-model in css*/
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    ul {
        display: flex;
/*no need to make flex direction : column. by default it applies row value and this will work fine.*/
        /* flex-direction: column; */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
/*currently no need of max-height. It is optional depends on your design.*/
        /* max-height: 200px; */
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    li {
        background: pink;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        /*0 is grow 0 is shrink 33.33% is basis*/
        flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the column width by adding

```css
width: 100px;
```

or whatever width you want to specify in the `ul` selector in your css

Comment: `ul` does not reflect the width of each column in this instance. The `ul` reflects the width of the entire row.

Comment: Fixed widths are not usually ideal in a responsive web.