# Using CSS Grid to have columns sized the same width as the largest one

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm building a grid layout using CSS Grid and I want **all my columns to have the same size** (fixed sized) and that size being the one of **the largest column**.
I know that I can do it using JS or even `display: table` but I would like to do it using CSS Grid (if it's possible).

Here's what I have:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 120px);
  gap: 5px;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Orange</span>
  <span>Purple</span>
  <span>Aquamarine</span>
  <span>Black</span>
  <span>Brown</span>
  <span>Red</span>
</div>
```

I fixed the width at 120px but I want that width to be the one of **Aquamarine** which is the largest one.

Comment: fixed size to the biggest one + wrapping is not possible with CSS grid (or any CSS method)

Comment: If you're sure about your comment maybe write an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed number of columns, you can do it by placing your grid element inside a wrapper element styled with `display: inline-block;` and then setting `grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267092/2518285).

However, I don't know how to do this in a grid where you have a variable number of columns by using `auto-fit` or `auto-fill`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="grid">
  <span>Orange</span>
  <span>Purple</span>
  <span>Aquamarine</span>
  <span>Black</span>
  <span>Brown</span>
  <span>Red</span>
</div>
</div>
```