# Set width of buttons same as the button with maximum width in the row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a container `div.parent` and it has some `button` elements. The number of `button` elements at any given point of time are variable (they may change). The `div.parent` is currently `display: flex` with `flex-direction: row` and some other basic css properties.

So, if there are say, four buttons in the row at a given time, each obviously would have its own width according to the content in it. Say, the widths are `55px`, `72px`, `78px`, `60px`.  This does not fit well with the design language. I want all the buttons to have same width so that they look better. So, in this case, I would want that all the buttons have a width of `78px` which is the maximum. (Because choosing another width, say `72px` would not look good on the button with `78px` width, so we always choose the maximum.)

I tried using `display: flex` and could not find a way in css to automatically adjust the width of the button according to the maximum width. Also, I was willing to use `table` but as per the semantics, it is meant to use for tabular data, not decoration. Cannot even think of a way to lay the buttons out using `display: grid`.

Here is a demonstration of how I want the buttons to be arranged. Note that, here I manually set the widths of the button, but I need an automatic css layout that sets the button width equal to the maximum width button.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ddddff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.parent button {
  margin: 0 4px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<h2> How I want it </h2>
<span>All the buttons should have the same width, and the width should equal to maximum of the widths of all the buttons. In this case, I manually set the button width.</span>
<div class="parent">
  <button> Button </button>
  <button> Another Button </button>
  <button> Yet Another </button>
</div>
```

How can I achieve it using CSS?

Comment: Usually, a runnable script of the current state of your app helps greatly. Look for the option "JS/HTML/CSS Snippet" in the edit panel, top menu item with  a `<>` icon on a page.

Comment: @alegria Okay, editting the question...

Comment: Check the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/q/29503227/5602521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using CSS grid

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  background: #ddddff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.parent button {
  margin: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<h2> How I want it </h2>
<span>All the buttons should have the same width, and the width should equal to maximum of the widths of all the buttons. In this case, I manually set the button width.</span>
<div class="parent">
  <button> Button </button>
  <button> Another Button </button>
  <button> Yet Another </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am never able to find the duplicate of this. Need to re-try with different keywords

Comment: Great! I liked it. Even though the parent's width is affected (as I can see by default), but the buttons actually behave the way I want them to.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve equal width for all buttons by using the CSS display: flex property on the .parent container along with the flex property on the buttons. To make sure all buttons have a width of 78px, you can use the flex: 1 property on each button. This will give equal width to buttons.

Comment: Nice solution, but the problem is that both the buttons take the full space available of their parent. For example, if one button has 100px width, and other has 120px width, while the container has 400px available, then they would fit in to use 200px of width each, which is not what I want. I just want all the buttons to share the width of the button that has maximum width.